# Не меняется язык в приложении

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь изменить язык в приложении, выводится Toast.makeText на экран с текстом нового языка, а вот контент на русском языке никак не хочет показываться. Все равно показывает все на английском.
При повторном включении приложения контент все равно на английском.
В самом эмуляторе я тоже поставила русский как родной язык. Но и это не помогло.

Изменяю язык -

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
        locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = this.getResources();
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        config.setLocale(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

            Toast.makeText(this, Locale.getDefault()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // показывает новый язык

recreate(); // активити не пересоздает.
```

`startActivity(new Intent(this, LanguageActivity.class));` так я тоже пробовола пересоздать активити. Активити создается заново, а контент по прежнему на английском

При повторном включении приложения контент все равно на английском.

Манифест -

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="locale">

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LanguageActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/DialogActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            />
      <activity
            android:name=".activities.SampleActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            >
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли пересоздать активити. Для этого можете у оной вызвать метод `recreate()`

Comment: `recreate()`, наверное, вы имели ввиду

Comment: @woesss, да, конечно) Поправил)

Comment: в таком случае, Активити пытается перезапуститься бесконечно

Comment: Так будет только если вы так код напишете) Вам надо делать пересоздание активити только после смены языка. Например, сохраняя куда-то выбранный юзером язык и пересоздавать активити только после выбора оного. Если вы пересоздание запустите просто в onCreate, то, конечно, будет бесконечный перезапуск. Наверное, вы меняете язык при нажатии на к-л кнопку - вот там же и пересоздавайте активити

Comment: В таком случае, Активити даже не перезапускается, контент также остается на английском при повторном включении приложения или самой Активити вручную с помощью кнопок

Comment: Наверное, вы что то не так делаете. Покажите код где вы меняете язык. Нужно больше кода)

Comment: Я добавила код.

Comment: Из кода не видно в какой момент вы меняете локаль. Приведённый код находится в слушателе нажатий кнопки или просто в onCreate активити? И попробуйте убрать `android:configChanges="locale"` - вроде бы оно должно предотвращать пересоздание активити при смене локали, т.е. мешает сделать то, что нужно сделать - пересоздать активити.